# keeping first observation of each duplicated combination of values across multiple colums

Tags: r, dplyr

My data :

```
    var1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 28, 6)
    var2 <- c(2, 1, 10, 11, 6, 78, 5)
    var3 <- c(100,101,102,0,0,0, 0)
    dataset<- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
    datset
```

my result :

```
  var1 var2 var3   
    1   2   100     
    2   1   101     
    3   10  102 
    4   11  0       
    5   6   0       
    28  78  0       
    6   5   0
```

I have two combinations of duplicated values across the `var1` and `var2` columns (in any order):
first one:

```
  var1 var2 var3   
    1   2   100 
    2   1   101
```

second one:

```
  var1 var2 var3   
    5   6   0               
    6   5   0
```

Expected result :
keeping first observation of each duplicated combinaison of values in multiple colums (`var1` and `var2`) :

```
  var1 var2 var3   
    1   2   100 
    3   10  101 
    4   11  102 
    5   6   0       
    28  78  0
```

full dataset [csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cE_jiRVgrHRMD1fcGjX7sj4rqehLB1PYB4ZzvOdOBTw)

Answer (score 3):

We can use `duplicated` on the `sort`ed elements of each row of the first two columns to get the expected output

```
dataset[!duplicated(t(apply(dataset[1:2], 1, sort))),]
```

---

Or another option is to apply `duplicated` on `pmin` and `pmax`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataset)[!duplicated(dataset[, .(var1 = pmin(var1, var2), var2 = pmax(var1, var2))])]
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's full dataset

```
df1 <- na.omit(read.csv(file.choose(), row.names = 1))
out <- df1[!duplicated(t(apply(df1[1:2], 1, sort))),]
dim(out)
#[1] 113   3


out2 <- setDT(df1)[!duplicated(df1[, .(from = pmin(from, to), to = pmax(from, to))])]
dim(out2)
#[1] 113   3
```

Comment: @Wilcar Is there any non-numeric elements in the original dataset?

Comment: @Wilcar Its not clear when you say it is not working.  Can you be bit more specific or update with a more reproducible example

Comment: I updated my question with a link to my real dataset. (columns "from"(2)  and "to"(3)). egg of duplicated :  3 and 2 : 2 and 3

Comment: @Wilcar  I get 113 rows after removing the duplicates

Comment: @Wilcar It could be that when you read the dataset the row names also got read as the first column.  In my code, we are subsetting the 1st 2 columns, so, this created an imbalance.  I would always check the `str` of the data being read because there could be some issues in formats and other things

Comment: Thank you fort the advice and your help @akrun